# How to handle an error from fetch API when closing/unloading in async context?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await, fetch

I wrote the following code to `fetch` data in my application. I want to wrap *all* `TypeError: Failed to fetch` thrown by `fetch` into a dedicated application error object (`FetchError`), but sometimes it fails to handle and the raw `TypeError` shows up at the console in some user's environment.

```js
const fetchApi = async (url, init) => {
    let response = null;
    try {
        response = await fetch(url, init);
    } catch (e) {
        throw new FetchError(`Failed to fetch ${url}`, e);
    }
    if (response.ok) {
        const data = await parse(response);
        return { response, data };
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

I suspect that the browser implementation (at least Chrome) terminates `fetch` in async context and skips executing the following `catch` clause (it is actually a reject side of the `Promise.then` function) when closing or unloading a browser window executing my application. How to deal with the situation?

Answer (score -1):

`The Promise returned from fetch() won’t reject on HTTP error status even if the response is an HTTP 404 or 500. Instead, it will resolve normally (with ok status set to false), and it will only reject on network failure or if anything prevented the request from completing`

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

You could try something like this:

```
const fetchApi = async (url, init) => {
    let response = null;
    try {
        response = await $.ajax({
            url: url
        })
        return response
    } catch (e) {
        throw new FetchError(`Failed to fetch ${url}`, e.responseText);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't use jQuery in my product.